# The cheapest offcut carpet to buy for two rooms word problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image: Question]

**Correct answer: C**

This might come of as a slightly dumby question, but I've been googling for a while and have gone nowhere.

What I presumed the question was asking was to add up the two areas of the rooms, and choose the carpet area that is as close to that one, but bigger as possible. My answer was D ( the closest to 14.88, the combined area of the two rooms).

Am I not understanding the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you arrange a $2.6m\times 4.4m$ rectangle, and a $1.8m\times 2.2m$ rectangle, on a $2.6m\times 5.8m$ rectangle without overlap?  If you can, then you can cut out the two pieces from the big rectangle to carpet your office.